# What is the Expectations of all 3 ants meeting at same point?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Say we have 3 ants in three corner's of triangle. What is the expectations that all 3 ants meeting together given that the ant moves in any direction. So by just seeing it I figured out  that in 2 ways  all three Ant can meet together in either in A ,B or C . But i think it is a two state discrete time markov chain problem.

Ant in A moving to B and then A  with the Ant in B moving to C and then A and Ant in C moving to B and then A
Ant in A moving to C and then A with the Ant in B moving to C and then A and Ant in C moving to B and then A

This will apply for all 3 ant meeting at B and C . But Is it right?

Comment: Is it meant that the direction is chosen only once, and the ants move with the same speed on the sides of the triangle?

Comment: @ Ilya :No it can move in any direction and speed is same. So it is to do with transient probability.

Comment: Just thinking ,We have three states 
State A : ant at each vertex
State B : two ants at same vertex
State C : three ants at a single vertex

3x-3y = 4
2y –x =5
So X is 7.6. Just moving from one state to another

Comment: Does the ant pick up a direction only at the initial step? Even in such case, think of just any two ants - what is the probability that they will pass by some point at the same time (if that's what you mean by meeting)?

Comment: No, Say one possibility of all 3 ants meeting together in A is the Ant in A has to move B and the ant in B has to move C and the ant in C has to move B .So we have two ants in B and one ant in C at the end of the first round . In the second round, Both the ant in B will go to Aand the ant in C moves to A. So at the end of round 2 , you have three ants in A. So this is nothing but two state markov chain. But What is the expectation of all three ants meeting together?

Comment: So you are talking about a discrete-time case, when ants can only be at one of the vertices, but not at any other point of the plain/triangle? That is, instead of "choosing a direction" they choose a vertex?

Comment: ya correct. But the ant can go to any vertices. Say Ant in A can go to B and C on any round.

Answer (score 2):

In section 3.3 of *Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability* by Blom, Holst, and Sandell, the authors solve this problem. Here is their solution.

> Three ants start at different corners of a triangle.
>   At every time point, each ant independently jumps to a new corner, either to the left or to the right with probability 1/2 each. 
>    Eventually, all three ants will meet at one corner and the game is finished. 
>   How long on average until this happens?

Define "state 1" to be when all ants are at different corners, "state 2" when 
two ants are at one corner, and the third ant is at a different corner, and 
"state 3" when they are all together. The diagram 
below illustrates how we might move from state 1 to state 2.

[image]

We are interested in $M$, the number of steps needed to finish the game, starting in state 1. 
To solve this problem, we also need the random variable $N$, 
 the number of steps needed to finish starting in state 2.

To begin, imagine starting in state 1. There are eight equally likely 
possibilities depending on how the ants jump. In two of the cases
we remain in state 1, and in six cases we end up in state 2. Hence
$$M=\cases{1+M^\prime&with probability $1/4$\cr 1+N&with probability $3/4$,}$$
where $M^\prime$ has the same distribution as $M$.

Now imagine starting in state 2. There are eight equally likely 
possibilities depending on how the ants jump. In one case
all the ants go to the same corner and the game is finished. 
Otherwise, in five cases we stay in state 2, 
and in two cases we go to  state 1.

Therefore 
$$N=\cases{1&with probability $1/8$\cr
  1+ N^\prime&with probability $5/8$\cr 
              1+M&with probability $1/4$,}$$
where $N^\prime$ has the same distribution as $N$.

From these relationships, we find that the probability generating functions
 satisfy 
\begin{eqnarray*}
G_M(s)&=&{s\over 4}\, G_M(s)+{3s\over 4}\,G_N(s),\\[5pt]
G_N(s)&=&{s\over8}+{5s\over 8}\, G_N(s)+{s\over 4}\,G_M(s).
\end{eqnarray*}

Solving this system of equations shows that 
$$G_M(s)={3s^2\over 32-28s-s^2}={3\over 32}\,s^2+{21\over 256}\,s^3+{153\over 2048}\,s^4+{1113\over 16384}\,s^5+\cdots.$$
Differentiating $G_M$ and setting $s=1$ gives $\mathbb{E}(M)=G_M^\prime(1)=12.$

Comment: +1, but we don't really need generating functions (though they give more information): assuming the existence of $E[M]$ and $E[N]$, the two relationships directly give $E[M] = 1 + \frac14E[M] + \frac34E[N]$ (so $3E[M] - 3E[N] = 4$), and $E[N] = 1 + \frac58E[N] + \frac28E[M]$ (so $3E[N] - 2E[M] = 8$) solving which gives $E[M] = 12$ and $E[N] = 32/3$.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You are absolutely right. In their book, the authors ask for both the mean and variance of $M$. In that case, the effort in finding the full probability generating function is worth it, I guess.